# Python Popen writing to stdin not working when in a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

I'm trying to write a program that simultaneously reads and writes to a process's std(out/in) respectively. However, it seems that writing to a program's stdin in a thread does not work. Here's the relevant bits of code:

```
import subprocess, threading, queue

def intoP(proc, que):
    while True:
        if proc.returncode is not None:
            break
        text = que.get().encode() + b"\n"
        print(repr(text))      # This works
        proc.stdin.write(text) # This doesn't.


que = queue.Queue(-1)

proc = subprocess.Popen(["cat"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

threading.Thread(target=intoP, args=(proc, que)).start()

que.put("Hello, world!")
```

What's going wrong, and is there a way to fix it?

I'm running python 3.1.2 on Mac OSX, it's confirmed that it works in python2.7.

Comment: I'm on 3.1.2, why would it not work in a future version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is - buffering. If you add a

```
proc.stdin.flush()
```

after the `proc.stdin.write()` call, you'll see "Hello, world!" printed to the console (by the subprocess), as you'd expect.

Comment: thanks!  Wonder why this works (not having the flush)  on Py2 but not Py3?

Answer (score 0):

I changed proc.stdin.write(text) to proc.communicate(text), and that works in Python 3.1.

Comment: I don't want to use `communicate()` because there is a parallel thread handling the stdout of the program. I need to read and write independently.

Comment: `communicate()` reads until the end of file is reached anyway, and this is meant to keep running. It's not just one time I will be communicating.